# How to take lists containing exactly 2 identical elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have `L` which is a big list of small list as follows.

```
L = Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]
```

I want to take only small lists containing exactly 2 identical elements, for example, `{a,b,a}`, `{b,b,a}`, `{a,b,b}`, etc but not `{a,a,a}`, `{b,b,b}` and `{c,c,c}`.

How to do so?

## Edit

This question came in my mind while I was trying to compare my explicit calculation on the following problem with iteration performed by Mathematica.

> Assume that there are only 365 days in a year. Among 250 students, what is the probability in which there is exactly a single pair consists of exactly 2 students with the same birthday?

I reduced the problem by changing the days to blood types and the 250 students to 3 students just for simplicity.

Comment: I think this question should be sharpened a bit. What if lists are of length 4, and there are two pairs of identical elements, say `{a, a, b, b}`? Should such a list be accepted? How about a case like `{a, a, a, b, b}`? Answer by @C.E. would accept this. Without more precision, multiple answers with differing results on extended cases of longer than 3-tuples are possible.

Comment: @kirma: See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select[L, 2 === Length@Union@# &]
```

**Update**: I realized that `DeleteDuplicates` should be slightly faster than `Union` even on small lists. If enough of them this could make a noticeable difference, so I figured I'd do some testing.

Setup, first build a large set of lists:

```
Length[L = Tuples[syms = a /@ Range[180], 3]]
```

output:

> 5832000

```
RepeatedTiming[Select[2 === Length@Union@# &]@L;]
```

> {15.0, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[Select[2 === Length@DeleteDuplicates@# &]@L;]
```

> {14., Null}

So by the time we've got almost 6 million Unions vs DeleteDuplicates at length 3 lists it does make a bit of a difference.

And just to compare against the fastest (by far) of **C.E.**'s nice examples:

```
RepeatedTiming[ Cases[{Except[x_] ..., x_, Except[x_] ..., x_, Except[x_] ...}]@L;]
```

> {14., Null}

so equivalent at this level of testing to the `DeleteDuplicates` example but faster than the original `Union`. All of these much faster than:

```
RepeatedTiming[Select[2 === Max@(Last /@ Tally[#]) &]@L;]
```

> {41.061, Null}

Answer (score 2):

Define

```
syms = {a, b, c, d};
l = Tuples[syms, 3]
```

A pattern based option:

```
Cases[l, {Except[x_] ..., x_, Except[x_] ..., x_, Except[x_] ...}]
```

and an option not using patterns:

```
ops = Count /@ syms;
Select[l, MemberQ[2]@*Through@*ops]
```